# Jquery clone() : Clone elements not showing in output as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery `clone()` for first time. Seems it's not working as expected. The output should be entire HTML with the updated page-title.

```
var test = '<section class="fine-print clearfix"><p class="copyright">&#169; 2012 by <a href="test.com" target="_blank">ABCD</a>. All rights reserved.<h1 class="page-title">Default Template</h1></section>';

var x = $(test);
var z = x.clone();
var s = z.find('.page-title').html('<div id="FSPpageTitle" fsp="pageTitle"></div>');
alert(s.html());
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT (Entire HTML):

```
<section class="fine-print clearfix"><p class="copyright">&#169; 2012 by <a href="test.com" target="_blank">ABCD</a>. All rights reserved.<div id="FSPpageTitle" fsp="pageTitle"></div></section>
```

CODEPEN LINK: http://codepen.io/Lipak/pen/RKGvRK

Please help !!

Comment: You are targeting the result of the `find`instead of the clone. Added answer but voting to close as typo too :)

Comment: console.log every var you create, and then see what you are actually looking for...

Comment: What if the **fine-print** class wrapped with <!DOCTYPE html></html>. In this case i want in output everything should come. http://codepen.io/Lipak/pen/RKGvRK

Comment: top level html elements are stripped out by `$()`. Basically you can't as `$()` flattens the DOM a little ignoring elements like HEAD and HTML (and DOCTYPE)

Comment: @GoneCoding Any other solution for this ? Actually i want entire HTML including <!DOCTYPE> should come in the output.

Comment: The only way to do that is the immediately replace the entire HTML of the document object itself (basically replacing the whole page). You can't parse full HTML with `$()` as it only allows a very structured sub-set of HTML.

Comment: @GoneCoding If you don't mind can you help me in the codepen link you provided as i'm a newbie.

Comment: You need to explain what this *is actually going to be used for* if you want a solution to your actual problem. What you have at the moment is a piece of code that will never do what you think you want, but I don't know what you actually need (yet) :)

Comment: @GoneCoding Actually i'm building a HTML code conversion application where it will take the ENTIRE HTML as input from user and convert the  code by targeting the class name and RETURN back the ENTIRE  HTML CONVERTED code to user.

Comment: @GoneCoding For your information what i exactly want to do. Plase look into this link :: http://codepen.io/Lipak/pen/RKGdev

Comment: You might be able to cheat using an iFrame, as that can contain your entire HTML including initial marker elements and HEAD, BODY etc, but you will not be able to simply use jQuery to parse it as it is not designed to cope with full page HTML.

Comment: @GoneCoding I found something from internet. https://gist.github.com/cowboy/742952 This is the solution ?

Comment: That is a plugin, and does look like it will support parsing the entire HTML page. It does a number of text replacements to make the HTML edible by jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

You wanted `z`, not `s`, as `s` is the result of the `find`.

i.e.

```
alert(z.html());
```

The reason you cannot see the outer `section` is because html() returns the inner HTML. You can view it properly with `alert(z[0].outerHTML)`.

`z[0]` returns the underlying DOM element for the jQuery wrapped element, from which you can display normal DOM properties like `outerHTML`.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZgMjN

Regarding the extra question you added in comment, about full HTML being provided: top level html elements are stripped out by `$()`. Basically you can't do it as `$()` flattens the DOM a little ignoring elements like HEAD and HTML (and DOCTYPE)

Comment: No, I need **S** , which will update the inner HTML value of class **page-title** and return the entire html.

Comment: @LipakSahil: So basically you were misusing `html()` and not `clone()` :)

Answer (score 0):

DO in this way it will work you have just update H1 tag's HTML but not select updated HTML please try as below.

```
var test = '<section class="fine-print clearfix"><p class="copyright">&#169; 2012 by <a href="test.com" target="_blank">ABCD</a>. All rights reserved.<h1 class="page-title">Default Template</h1></section>';

var x = $(test);
var z = x.clone();
z.find('.page-title').html('<div id="FSPpageTitle" fsp="pageTitle"></div>');
alert(z[0].outerHTML);
```

Comment: As your answer is now identical after edit, why bother posting it?

Comment: @GoneCoding ohhh yeah u r right just making things more convenient for user

Comment: Leaving it to you. The OP has clarified that the question is clear as mud :)

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But why I'm missing the **fine-print** class ?

Comment: @LipakSahil: Now I can see what you are talking about I have updated my answer to explain :)

Comment: Yes @GoneCoding is right about this i have updated my answer as well for future references..

Comment: Thanks it's working. But one more question if you don't mind ?

Comment: @LipakSahil yes yes go for it we are here to help :-)